# Copy PivotTable value and formats with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two PivotTables in a sheet that I want to copy to a new sheet in a new file, I want the tables to be the same length width etc.

But The code am using does not store the colors of the cells and in the new file it is no longer a PivotTable, it becomes plain data:

```vb
Sub RefreshPivotTables()

    Dim wb As Workbook, newWb As Workbook
    
    Dim pt1 As PivotTable, pt2 As PivotTable
    Dim newFileName As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set Admin = wb.Sheets("Administration")
    Set pt1 = wb.Sheets("GDM-MO").PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique1")
    Set pt2 = wb.Sheets("GDM-MO").PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique2")

    ' Refresh PivotTables
    pt1.RefreshTable
    pt2.RefreshTable
    
    
    ' Copy the first PivotTable
    pt1.TableRange2.Copy
    With newWb.Sheets(1).Range("A4")
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues ' Paste values
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats ' Paste formats
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths ' Paste column widths
    End With

    ' Find the last row used by the first PivotTable
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = newWb.Sheets(1).Cells(newWb.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    ' Copy the second PivotTable
    pt2.TableRange2.Copy
    With newWb.Sheets(1).Range("A" & lastRow + 6)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    End With
    
    ' PT Names
    With newWb.Sheets(1).Range("A2")
        .Value = "First Table"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
        .Font.Size = 11
    End With
    
    With newWb.Sheets(1).Range("A" & lastRow + 3)
        .Value = "Second Table"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
        .Font.Size = 11
    End With


    ' Name new workbook
    newFileName = "Extract tables (" & wb.Name & ").xlsx"
    
    ' Save File
    newWb.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & newFileName
End Sub
```

I want to have the same PivotTables that I have in my current file, be copied to the new files keeping all the style/formats/colors associated to them.

I know there are a lot of similar answers about this, but there they are too old, I just wanted to see if there is a more modern and easier solution.

Comment: You can't copy a pivot table to another file without bringing the source data with it. And since you have: `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` then it will be values (plain data). Perhaps if you make it `xlAll` but I think that will link the sourcedata. *I just wanted to see if there is a more modern and easier solution.* VBA has not had any real updates in many years so what you can find is probably what works.

Comment: Thank you that did it, I didn't think it will be this easy, even in the other answers hey didn't mention this.